# Python - splitting a log and searching for something specific

Tags: python

I have an assignment and I was wondering if you could help. For part of the question I am required to analyse a system log. The log contains information such as time and date, if root access was attempted for and from what ip address the attempt came from.

My question is: how do I loop through the log and pull out the ip addresses.

```
myFile = open('syslog','r') 
for line in myFile.readlines():
list_of_line = line.split(' ')
```

So here I've split the list up but how can I loop through trying to locate an ip address. Previously I have used locations but this isn't practical as it only looks for one address. I want it to search through and find all addresses so would that mean looking for strings with a certain length e.g. xxx.xxx.xx.xx as the ip address and specify that I am looking for numeric values.

edit-

```
Jan 10 09:32:07 j4-be03 sshd[3876]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.241.173.35  user=root
Jan 10 09:32:09 j4-be03 sshd[3876]: Failed password for root from 218.241.173.35 port 47084 ssh2
Jan 10 09:32:17 j4-be03 sshd[3879]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.241.173.35  user=root
Jan 10 09:32:19 j4-be03 sshd[3879]: Failed password for root from 218.241.173.35 port 47901 ssh2   
Jan 10 09:32:26 j4-be03 sshd[3881]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.241.173.35  user=root
Jan 10 09:32:29 j4-be03 sshd[3881]: Failed password for root from 218.241.173.35 port 48652 ssh2
```

I've been told to ignore the line containing `pam_unix` and focus on the line containing "Failed password for root" as they are duplicate entries. About to try the regular expression one now although I really don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Someone's going to post a regular expression here, which isn't going to be the best option. Unless you're happy with regular expressions combing through every bit of your log, post a couple of lines from the log here, so we can show you `.split()`.

Comment: You don't need `readlines()` because a file object is an iterator. Just do: `for line in open('syslog','r'):...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
myFile = open('syslog','r') 
ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', myFile.read() )
print ip
```

Don't you just love python?

Comment: Two problems: (1) findall won't work with a list of strings as the second input, and (2) this regex will match "1.2.3.4" when given "1.2.3.4.5", which probably isn't intended.

Comment: (1) True. I changed it to 'read()'. (2) I assume that he will not be given that in a log file, but that is a good point too.

Comment: worked well, however there are duplicate entries in the logs. I only need to take note of lines containing 'Failed password for root'. I'm very unfamiliar with regular expressions so could you explain exactly what is going on with the third line of code please?

Answer (score 1):

- to preselect lines that contain a certain string you could use `if s in line`
- to extract ip you could exploit the fact that you know strings that go before/after the ip

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/zMx0q)

```
prefix = "Failed password for root from"
def extract_ip(line):
    # get string between `prefix` and 'port'
    return line.partition(prefix)[2].partition('port')[0].strip()

with open('syslog') as f:
     ips = [extract_ip(line) for line in f if prefix in line]
```

In general it is a job for a regex to tokenize input.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (albeit a little unwieldy) is to split each string in `list_of_line` using period as your delimiter. Once you've done that you can check to see if the array you've generated is 4 items long, which would indicate that it is an IP, whereupon you can grab the original string from `list_of_line` and do whatever you need to with it. Do you want some psuedocode?

Note: While this approach is simple and readable, it does have a few drawbacks. First, it's probably somewhat slow, although if this is an assignment, speed most likely isn't really a problem. Secondly, you may have other items in `list_of_line` which have the same format as an IP (I suppose that's pretty unlikely, though), in which case you'd get non-IP results in your list of IPs. Just a few things to be aware of.

The other solution would be to use Python's Regex function -- you can just Google that for more info, it's a bit complicated.